Way to make two differently sharp and smooth specular shines? (Blender 3.3.0)
In a modeling software called Paint 3D, there is a lighting option which presumably has 2 lights, one with a very small, dot like sunlight, and a smoother, larger radius sunlight. Howver it is a fairly locked down software, which makes it impossible to see its configuration.

However I cannot achieve this, as (Angle) cannot go lower than 0. I tried adjusting the fac value too, but it makes the lights unsmoothable. What node setup could allow 2 different Fac inverts? How could I simplify this?


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Have you tried playing with a very small and intense spot light?



Spotlights are not a global solution, what I need is a sunlight or sunlight like shine globally that mimics this.

Use a Sun light and play with its angle property.


The thing is, the angle is already at the lowest it can be and adjusting the strength value wouldnt have any help in making it dot/pin-like. https://imgur.com/a/h55QGzE

Then I'm afraid this is simply not possible with a physically based renderer and a sun light
